# Как "увидеть" Java

Tags: java, eclipse, интерфейс

Практикуясь в программировании я вижу выполнение программы в Eclipse, на чем и как ещё можно тестировать Java программы и приложения? 
 Уточню, при создании приложения на Android мы можем запустить его на виртуальном устройстве или на своём телефоне, пусть даже оно пустое, без пользовательского интерфейса. Но мы увидим иконку приложения, можем её запустить. А как можно "увидеть" Java? Только ли в среде Eclipse? Или возможны другие варианты как: рабочий стол , всплывающее окно и.т.п.
 Другими словами, что нужно "накодить" для того что-бы визуализировать код. Какие функции и команды создают интерфейс для общения (или создания обратной связи) с пользователем?

Comment: Вы хотите запустить Java-программу на android? Вам нужен ярлык для запуска Java-программы на десктопе? вопрос не очень понятен, попробуйте сформулировать его так, чтобы можно было понять вашу проблему даже людям, которые о ней не имеют никакого представления.

Answer (score 2):

Вы спрашиваете «как использовать Java без Eclipse»?
Если да, то это не трудно:

1. Создайте текстовый файл с расширением `.java`, например `HelloWorld.java` и напишите в нем класс `HelloWorld`, содержащий метод `public static void main(String[] args)`.
2. В командной строке переместитесь в папку с файлом `HelloWorld.java` и выполните команду `javac HelloWorld.java`
3. А потом выполните команду `java -classpath . HelloWorld`. Появится файл `HelloWorld` — ваша скомпилированная программа, которую можно запустить.

Подробности можно найти [в этой статье](https://habrahabr.ru/post/125210/), например.